# OV7670 camera module (no FIFO chip) configuration with arduino Uno R4 WIFI

Tags: camera, arduino-uno, image-sensor

a couple of days ago I bought this camera module to use for my project which also does not require a lot of resolution, since I haven't used this camera module before I did google and chat GPT. but the information on how to supply PCLK, HS, VS, and MCLK was not clear, and I almost found no reliable source of information. also, I do not know if any Arduino libraries provide the facilities to configure these clock signals. It would be helpful if any of you could say what to do and how to proceed.also any recommendations on Arduino libraries.

here is the pin configuration,(VS, HS, MCLK, PCLK pins on ov7670 are not connected)

```
Arduino pin----ov7670 pin
3.3v       --- 3.3
3.3v       --- RST
GND        --- GND
SCL        --- SCL(with 12K resistor)
SDA        --- SDA(with 12K resistor)
A2         --- D7
A3         --- D5
A4         --- D3
A5         --- D1
2          --- D0
3          --- D2
4          --- D4 
5          --- D6
PWNN       --- GND
```